# Named Parameter not getting recognized in jdbcTemplate.queryForList() method

Tags: java-8, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

I am getting below exception :

> ERROR 1 --- [eduler_Worker-3] jdbc.sqltiming
>   : 123. PreparedStatement.setObject(1, {ids=[33925]})
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of
>   range.
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from tableA t1 WHERE t1.id IN
>   (:ids)]; The index 1 is out of range.; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of
>   range.

Below is the code:

```
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void publish(List<Long> ids) {
        val result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from tableA t1 WHERE t1.id IN (:ids)",ImmutableMap.of("ids", ids));
}
```

I am unable to understand that why is it trying to put at index 1 while I am using named parameter in the query. Please help

Comment: JdbcTemplate doesn't support named parameters. Make sure you use  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-java.lang.Class-

Comment: Ahh my bad..thanks for the help